# Caching the data (files and folders) in windows explorer. Which approach should I take?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, vb.net, winapi

In my application, I am fetching the data from my server and showing
that data in windows explorer. The data is in the form of files and
folders. You can imagine like a mapped drive on my machine which has the
data on server, I can explore this data through windows explorer.

The problem with my application is that every time I open or close the folder it fetches the data from server. It's a
redundant call and raising performance issue as data size may grow to GB's.

What I am thinking is to cache that data on my machine, and it should work in sync with data on server.

How should I implement this? Can I use any light weight database as Cache on my machine? Or there is any other way to do this.

Comment: So, how often do these files change? How large are they? What is the consequence of "getting it wrong" (in other words, if you have either old or "some new, some old" content)? Before you answering the question in your post, we'd have to know what these things mean in your case.

Comment: Is this a custom shell integration with explorer? How are you fetching the data? smb/http? Whats its source?

Comment: @Alex it's shell integration and i am fetching the data by using http.

Comment: @Mats All these files may not change at the same time but some of them may change frequently. And in my case i am fetching all the files every time whether it's updated or not. Thanks..

Comment: There is the sync framework, which is pretty flexible although you would need to implement custom providers http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb902854(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @AlexK. I will explore this...thanks.